# Можно ли как то проверять операции QIWI в Python?

Tags: python, qiwi

Собственно вопрос в названии темы, можно ли как то осуществить это без всяких терминалов

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос ещё актуален?

Есть API Киви Кошелька https://developer.qiwi.com/qiwiwallet/qiwicom_ru.html
SDK для Python пока в разработке. Есть работающие примеры с помощью модуля sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Это работает немного не так. Вы можете подключить сервисы киви (или других агрегаторов платежных систем) для создания, к примеру, электронной кассы. Операции с ней могут происходит через запросы api, следовательно это возможно сделать из python'а

Answer (score 0):

У QIWI нет официального API, насколько я знаю. Но есть подпольные API с реализациями различных запросов на PHP, которые можно переписать на python